# Ubuntu Studio menu audio, video production, graphics directory menu entry disappeared

Tags: sound, menu, ubuntu-studio, xdg

Ubuntu Studio menu has broken - I must have installed something or made a change to the menu (I used the menu editor to add a launcher), and I lost the audio production, video production and graphics menu entries.

Here is the list of files in `~/.local/share/desktop-directories`:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxxx xxxxx 204 Jul  6 07:59 ubuntustudio-audioproduction.directory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxxx xxxxx 211 Jul  5 10:32 ubuntustudio-graphics.directory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxxx xxxxx 204 Jul  5 10:32 ubuntustudio-videoproduction.directory
```

Here is the list of files in `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxxx xxxxx 271 Jul  6 08:00 menulibre-new-launcher.desktop
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxxx xxxxx   0 Jun 22 14:35 mimeapps.list
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxxx xxxxx  14 Jul  6 07:57 mimeinfo.cache
```

I tried using menulibre to edit the visibility by changing the 'Hide from menus' button to on, in the hope that I could change it to off to rewrite the config files but it wouldn't change from off.

Here is the contents of the file at `~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Menu
  PUBLIC '-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN'
  'http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-1.0.dtd'>
<Menu>
    <Name>Xfce</Name>
    <DefaultAppDirs />
    <DefaultDirectoryDirs />
    <DefaultMergeDirs />
    <Include>
        <Category>X-Xfce-Toplevel</Category>
    </Include>
    <MergeFile type="parent">/etc/xdg/menus/xfce-applications.menu</MergeFile>
    <Menu>
        <Name>ubuntustudio-videoproduction</Name>
        <Directory>ubuntustudio-videoproduction.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>ubuntustudio-graphics</Name>
        <Directory>ubuntustudio-graphics.directory</Directory>
        <DirectoryDir>/home/super/.local/share/desktop-directories</DirectoryDir>
        <Menu>
            <Name>ubuntustudio-photography</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-photography.directory</Directory>
            <Layout>
                <Merge type="menus" />
                <Merge type="files" />
            </Layout>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <Name>Utilities</Name>
            <Directory>X-GNOME-Utilities.directory</Directory>
            <Layout>
                <Merge type="menus" />
                <Merge type="files" />
            </Layout>
        </Menu>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Menuname>ubuntustudio-photography</Menuname>
            <Menuname>Utilities</Menuname>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>ubuntustudio-audioproduction</Name>
        <Directory>ubuntustudio-audioproduction.directory</Directory>
        <Menu>
            <Name>ubuntustudio-audio-utiliy</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-audio-utiliy.directory</Directory>
            <Layout>
                <Merge type="menus" />
                <Merge type="files" />
            </Layout>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <Name>ubuntustudio-effects</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-effects.directory</Directory>
            <Layout>
                <Merge type="menus" />
                <Merge type="files" />
            </Layout>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <Name>ubuntustudio-synths</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-synths.directory</Directory>
            <Layout>
                <Merge type="menus" />
                <Merge type="files" />
            </Layout>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <Name>ubuntustudio-midi</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-midi.directory</Directory>
            <Layout>
                <Merge type="menus" />
                <Merge type="files" />
            </Layout>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <Name>ubuntustudio-mixers</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-mixers.directory</Directory>
            <Layout>
                <Merge type="menus" />
                <Merge type="files" />
            </Layout>
        </Menu>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Menuname>ubuntustudio-audio-utiliy</Menuname>
            <Menuname>ubuntustudio-effects</Menuname>
            <Menuname>ubuntustudio-synths</Menuname>
            <Menuname>ubuntustudio-midi</Menuname>
            <Menuname>ubuntustudio-mixers</Menuname>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Accessories</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-accessories.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>xfce4-about.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-appfinder.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>file-roller.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>Thunar-bulk-rename.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gnome-calculator.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>catfish.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gucharmap.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>exo-file-manager.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>menulibre.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>mc.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>mcedit.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>mousepad.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-notes.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>onboard.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>onboard-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>Thunar-folder-handler.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>globaltime.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>apport-gtk.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-run.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-screenshooter.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-taskmanager.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>exo-terminal-emulator.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>terminator.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>Thunar.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>debian-uxterm.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>code.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfburn.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>debian-xterm.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Development</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-development.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>menulibre-new-launcher.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>org.gnome.Devhelp.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gitkraken.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>glade.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>python2.7.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>python3.5.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>assistant-qt4.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>designer-qt4.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>linguist-qt4.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>DigiaQt-qtcreator-community.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>Qt-MaintenanceTool.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>code.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>geany.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>nemiver.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Education</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-education.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>libreoffice-math.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xtide.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Electronics</Name>
        <Directory>Electronics.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>geda-gschem.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Games</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-games.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>gnome-mines.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>pingus.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>PlayOnLinux.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gnome-sudoku.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>teeworlds.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>HamRadio</Name>
        <Directory>HamRadio.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Network</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-network.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>firefox.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>google-chrome.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>hexchat.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>idjc.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>exo-mail-reader.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>pidgin.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qBittorrent.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>thunderbird.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>transmission-gtk.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>exo-web-browser.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>ubuntustudio-mediaplayback</Name>
        <Directory>ubuntustudio-mediaplayback.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Office</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-office.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>xfce4-dict.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>evince.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>libreoffice-startcenter.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>libreoffice-calc.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>libreoffice-math.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>libreoffice-writer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfcalendar.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>globaltime.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>evince-previewer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>calligra.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_tga.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_png.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_psd.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_heightmap.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_odg.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_jpeg.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_xcf.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_exr.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_ora.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_ppm.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_bmp.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_raw.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_tiff.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_pdf.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_jp2.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Other</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-other.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>gcr-prompter.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>panel-desktop-handler.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>kmailservice5.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ktelnetservice5.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>libreoffice-xsltfilter.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>mono-runtime-common.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>mono-runtime-terminal.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>nm-applet.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gcr-viewer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>wine.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>openjdk-8-java.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>kmailservice.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ktelnetservice.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>System</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-system.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>boot-repair.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>Thunar-bulk-rename.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gcm-picker.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gcm-viewer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ubuntustudio-contribute.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gigolo.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gitkraken.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gparted.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>grub-customizer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gcm-import.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-session-logout.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>mc.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>network.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>Thunar-folder-handler.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>system-config-printer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>assistant-qt4.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>hplj1020.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gksu.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>shares.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>org.gnome.Software.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gnome-software-local-file.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>update-manager.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>synaptic.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>hardinfo.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-taskmanager.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>terminator.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>Thunar.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>time.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ubuntustudio-controls.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ubuntustudio-forum.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ubuntustudio-help.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ubuntustudio-irc.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ubuntustudio-mail.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ubuntustudio-installer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ubuntustudio-website.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>unetbootin.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>users.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>debian-uxterm.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-terminal.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>debian-xterm.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>ubuntustudio-noshow</Name>
        <Directory>ubuntustudio-noshow.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>wine-wine</Name>
        <Directory>wine-wine.directory</Directory>
        <Menu>
            <Name>wine-Programs</Name>
            <Directory>wine-Programs.directory</Directory>
            <Menu>
                <Name>wine-Programs-Accessories</Name>
                <Directory>wine-Programs-Accessories.directory</Directory>
                <Layout>
                    <Merge type="menus" />
                    <Filename>wine-notepad.desktop</Filename>
                    <Merge type="files" />
                </Layout>
            </Menu>
            <Layout>
                <Merge type="menus" />
                <Menuname>wine-Programs-Accessories</Menuname>
                <Merge type="files" />
            </Layout>
        </Menu>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Menuname>wine-Programs</Menuname>
            <Filename>wine-browsedrive.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>wine-winecfg.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>wine-uninstaller.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>winetricks.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>ubuntustudio-info</Name>
        <Directory>ubuntustudio-info.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Graphics</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-graphics.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>agave.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>blender.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>darktable.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>evince.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>entangle.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>fontforge.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>font-manager.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>font-sampler.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gimp.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>display-im6.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>display-im6.q16.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>inkscape.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_heightmap.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_ppm.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_tiff.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_xcf.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_pdf.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_png.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_jpeg.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_tga.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_psd.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_exr.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_odg.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_raw.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_jp2.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_bmp.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>krita_ora.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>mypaint.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>phatch-inspector.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>phatch.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>evince-previewer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>rapid-photo-downloader.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>rawtherapee.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ristretto.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>scribus.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>simple-scan.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>synfigstudio.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Multimedia</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-multimedia.directory</Directory>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>aeolus.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>amsynth.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ardour.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>zita-at1.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>audacity.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>brasero.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>cadence.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>calf.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>carla.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>carla-control.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>catia.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>claudia.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>claudia-launcher.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>clementine.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>devede_ng.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>drumkv1.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>echomixer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>envy24_control.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ffado.org-ffadomixer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>foo-yc20.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gladish.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gmidimonitor-alsa.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gmidimonitor-jack.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>guitarix.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>hdajackretask.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>hdspconf.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>hdspmixer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>hexter.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>hydrogen.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ingen.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>jack-keyboard.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>jack-rack.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>jamin.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>org.kde.kdenlive.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>kid3-qt.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ladi-player.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ladi-system-tray.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>lmms.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>lv2rack.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>meterbridge.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>midisnoop.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>mixxx.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>mudita24.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>muse.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>mscore.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>nekobee.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>non-mixer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>non-sequencer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>non-session-manager.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>non-timeline.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>openshot.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ll-scope.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>parole.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>patchage.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>petri-foo.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>phasex.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>pitivi.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>pavucontrol.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>puredata.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qasconfig.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qashctl.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qasmixer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qjackctl.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qmidiarp.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qmidinet.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qmidiroute.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qsampler.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qsynth.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>qtractor.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>rakarrack.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gtk-recordmydesktop.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>rmedigicontrol.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>rosegarden.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>samplv1.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>seq24.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>setbfree.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>sineshaper.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>sooperlooper.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>subtitleeditor.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>synthv1.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>vkeybd.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>vlc.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfburn.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xjadeo.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>yoshimi.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>zita-mu1.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>zita-rev1.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>zynaddsubfx-alsa.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>zynaddsubfx-jack.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>zynjacku.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Settings</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-settings.directory</Directory>
        <Menu>
            <Name>Screensavers</Name>
            <Directory>xfce-screensavers.directory</Directory>
            <Layout>
                <Merge type="menus" />
                <Merge type="files" />
            </Layout>
        </Menu>
        <Layout>
            <Merge type="menus" />
            <Filename>xfce-settings-manager.desktop</Filename>
            <Separator />
            <Filename>mugshot.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-accessibility-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>software-properties-drivers.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce-ui-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>blueman-adapters.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>blueman-manager.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>boot-repair.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gcm-calibrate.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce-backdrop-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce-display-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>thunar-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gparted.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>grub-customizer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce-keyboard-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ladi-control-center.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ladi-system-log.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>language-selector.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>menulibre.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-mime-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce-mouse-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>network.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>nm-connection-editor.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-notifyd-config.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>onboard-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>openjdk-8-policytool.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce-xfcalendar-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>panel-preferences.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-power-manager-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>exo-preferred-applications.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>system-config-printer.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>thunar-volman-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Menuname>Screensavers</Menuname>
            <Filename>xfce-session-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce4-settings-editor.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>shares.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>update-manager.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>software-properties-gtk.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>synaptic.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>gtk-theme-config.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>time.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>ubuntustudio-controls.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>users.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce-wm-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce-wmtweaks-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfce-workspaces-settings.desktop</Filename>
            <Filename>xfpanel-switch.desktop</Filename>
            <Merge type="files" />
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
    <Layout>
        <Filename>exo-web-browser.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-file-manager.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-terminal-emulator.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>xfce-settings-manager.desktop</Filename>
        <Separator />
        <Separator />
        <Menuname>ubuntustudio-videoproduction</Menuname>
        <Menuname>ubuntustudio-graphics</Menuname>
        <Menuname>ubuntustudio-audioproduction</Menuname>
        <Menuname>Accessories</Menuname>
        <Menuname>Development</Menuname>
        <Menuname>Education</Menuname>
        <Menuname>Electronics</Menuname>
        <Menuname>Games</Menuname>
        <Menuname>HamRadio</Menuname>
        <Menuname>Network</Menuname>
        <Menuname>ubuntustudio-mediaplayback</Menuname>
        <Menuname>Office</Menuname>
        <Menuname>Other</Menuname>
        <Menuname>System</Menuname>
        <Menuname>ubuntustudio-noshow</Menuname>
        <Menuname>wine-wine</Menuname>
        <Menuname>ubuntustudio-info</Menuname>
        <Filename>xfce4-about.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>exo-mail-reader.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>xfce4-run.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>xfce4-session-logout.desktop</Filename>
        <Filename>menulibre-new-launcher.desktop</Filename>
        <Menuname>Graphics</Menuname>
        <Menuname>Multimedia</Menuname>
        <Menuname>Settings</Menuname>
    </Layout>
</Menu>
```

Comment: To me it's not entirely clear what you want and you're asking. Do you want to restore the lost menu directories? Do you want to rebuild them from scratch?

Comment: Ubuntu Studio should have a menu for audio tools, and others.  Otherwise whiskermenu doesn't display the tools that I have installed.
The <Directory>ubuntustudio-audioproduction.directory</Directory> should be displaying according to the xdg file above but it is not.
I've tried purging and reinstalling the menu but to no avail.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what you want to achieve. …and please [edit] your question if you want to add information or clarify something. :-)

Comment: It should say "categories" instead of "directory" in the title of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there is a known issue in the menu editor currently shipped with Ubuntu Studio: MenuLibre.

When someone edits the Ubuntu Studio menu with right click on it, which opens MenuLibre editor, what he gets is a completely screwed up menu.

**Try to edit your menu by using application *Alacarte* instead of Menulibre. It should repair it; it has a button to restore the default menu.**  (If you can't find Alacarte inside your menu, just run the command `alacarte` in a terminal emulator.  If it's not installed, install it by running `sudo apt-get install alacarte`)

For those who want the technical details, this known issue is a currently [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/menulibre/+bug/1430571) for MenuLibre:

A possible explanation is given there in the bug report:

> It seems menulibre uses the system menufile `/etc/xdg/menus/xfce-applications.menu` rather than the file pointed to by session which is `/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntustudio/menus/xfce-applications.menu`. This is the file the session runs on and whisker and the application menu use. menulibre does not use this.
>
> Also menulibre makes its own whole new menu spec rather than just changing the parts of the menu you ask for. This is just wrong. I would suggest either doing these changes by hand or using alacart (alacart has problems as well) Ubuntustudio should remove menulibre from its list of applications.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?  I am using MenuLibre on Xubuntu 16.04 and it's working just fine.  Ubuntu Studio is based on Xubuntu.

Comment: Ok, I'll try, but the known issue is that, currently, MenuLibre usually screws up ubuntu studio Menu.  I found and solved this by googling two months ago, you will make me google all this again, it's all written somewhere out there.

Comment: I found some posts concerning this bug but they're referring to MenuLibre 2.0.4.  The version installed on Xubuntu 16.04 is 2.1.3.  Is there any chance it has been fixed?

Comment: Nope, this is currently happening on fresh installed Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS.  I don't know for Xubuntu, I haven't been using Xubuntu since 10.10, and I liked it too.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  This issue and its workaround should be listed in the known issues of Ubuntu Studio, meanwhile we'll try to help users from here.