# Xubuntu - Several categories missing from the Whisker menu

Tags: xubuntu, menu, whisker

[image: missing items]

The Accessories, Games, Internet, Other, and Wine categories are missing in the Whisker menu. They are not marked as hidden in menulibre. Additionally, I am unable to search for any items, searching for Firefox or Chrome does not give any results.

What in the world happened? I have no idea what could've gone wrong.

I have already tried removing the Whisker menu and adding it back, no change.

Comment: Use alacarte Details below: https://askubuntu.com/questions/795431/ubuntu-studio-menu-audio-video-production-graphics-directory-menu-entry-disapp